# Using a python webserver

Tags: python, http, webserver

I am looking for a web server, where I can upload files and download files from Ubuntu to Windows and the vice versa. I've builded a web server with Python and I share my folder in Ubuntu and download the files in this folder at Windows. Now I want to look up every millisecond if there is a new file and download this new files automatically. Is there any script or something helpfully for me?
Is a python web server a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to synchronise folders, even remote.
If you need to stick with the python server approach for some reason, look for file system events libraries to trigger your upload code (for example [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog)).
But if not, it may be simpler to use tools like [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) + [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), or simply [lsync](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd).

Good luck!

**Edit:** I just realized you want linux->windows sync, not the other way around, so since you don't have ssh server on the target (windows), rsync and lsync will not work for you, you probably need [smbclient](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html). In python, consider [pysmbc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysmbc) or [PySmbClient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySmbClient)

Comment: Is there a solution without a special software? And i want linux->windows and windows->linux.

Comment: You need SMB share. Turns out you can [permanently mount](http://askubuntu.com/questions/677773/transfer-file-to-windows-server-from-ubuntu-with-rsync) it on the Linux end and then simply use rsync.

Comment: But Samba is a software and i want a solution without a software :/

Comment: [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) is a protocol, [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) is an implementation of this protocol.